# Is there any mobile app that can pronounce the Hangul

Tags: translation

I've been learning the Hangul for a while now (since July) and so far I've been able to recognize the chatacthers and interpret a few words. Now my problem is when a see a word, that I know the meaning, its hard to pronounce it so I was wondering if there is any mobile app that takes the Hangul and like pronounce it. And maybe give the English interpretation.

Thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use Google Translate but it's sometimes wrong so to verify I use Naver dictionary https://en.dict.naver.com/
Naver it's huge in South Korea, it's like their Google.

In Naver, create an account and then after you can click on the  + sign next to the Korean word and it goes in your "Wordbook" and from there you can click on your saved words and you will be able to listen to the pronunciation by clicking on the speaker logo. I use the Safari browser on my iPhone to go on the Naver dictionary and it's working well. I always keep the window open.

For beginners Naver dictionary is enough and for the verbs conjugation simply search for it on Google and add "Conjugation", first results you will find what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

https://hangeul.naver.com/2011/pronunciation
http://pronunciation.cs.pusan.ac.kr/
ㄱ 가 ga

각 gak   간 gan   갈 gal   감 gam
갑 gap   갓 gat   강 gang  개 gae   객 gaek
거 geo   건 geon  걸 geol  검 geom  겁 geop
게 ge    겨 gyeo  격 gyeok 견 gyeon 결 gyeol
겸 gyeom 겹 gyeop 경 gyeong    계 gye   고 go
곡 gok   곤 gon   골 gol   곳 got   공 gong
곶 got   과 gwa   곽 gwak  관 gwan  괄 gwal
광 gwang 괘 gwae  괴 goe   굉 goeng 교 gyo
구 gu    국 guk   군 gun   굴 gul   굿 gut
궁 gung  권 gwon  궐 gwol  귀 gwi   규 gyu
균 gyun  귤 gyul  그 geu   극 geuk  근 geun
글 geul  금 geum  급 geup  긍 geung 기 gi
긴 gin   길 gil   김 gim   까 kka   깨 kkae
꼬 kko   꼭 kkok  꽃 kkot  꾀 kkoe  꾸 kku
꿈 kkum  끝 kkeut 끼 kki

ㄴ 나 na  낙 nak
난 nan   날 nal   남 nam   납 nap   낭 nang
내 nae   냉 naeng 너 neo   널 neol  네 ne
녀 nyeo  녁 nyeok 년 nyeon 념 nyeom 녕 nyeong
노 no    녹 nok   논 non   놀 nol   농 nong
뇌 noe   누 nu    눈 nun   눌 nul   느 neu
늑 neuk  늠 neum  능 neung 늬 nui   니 ni
닉 nik   닌 nin   닐 nil   님 nim

ㄷ 다 da

단 dan   달 dal   담 dam   답 dap   당 dang
대 dae   댁 daek  더 deo   덕 deok  도 do
독 dok   돈 don   돌 dol   동 dong  돼 dwae
되 doe   된 doen  두 du    둑 duk   둔 dun
뒤 dwi   드 deu   득 deuk  들 deul  등 deung
디 di    따 tta   땅 ttang 때 ttae  또 tto
뚜 ttu   뚝 ttuk  뜨 tteu  띠 tti

ㄹ 라 ra

락 rak   란 ran   람 ram   랑 rang  래 rae
랭 raeng 량 ryang 렁 reong 레 re    려 ryeo
력 ryeok 련 ryeon 렬 ryeol 렴 ryeom 렵 ryeop
령 ryeong    례 rye   로 ro    록 rok   론 ron
롱 rong  뢰 roe   료 ryo   룡 ryong 루 ru
류 ryu   륙 ryuk  륜 ryun  률 ryul  륭 ryung
르 reu   륵 reuk  른 reun  름 reum  릉 reung
리 ri    린 rin   림 rim   립 rip

ㅁ 마 ma

막 mak   만 man   말 mal   망 mang  매 mae
맥 maek  맨 maen  맹 maeng 머 meo   먹 meok
메 me    며 myeo  멱 myeok 면 myeon 멸 myeol
명 myeong    모 mo    목 mok   몰 mol   못 mot
몽 mong  뫼 moe   묘 myo   무 mu    묵 muk
문 mun   물 mul   므 meu   미 mi    민 min
밀 mil
ㅂ 바 ba

박 bak   반 ban   발 bal

밥 bap   방 bang  배 bae   백 baek  뱀 baem
버 beo   번 beon  벌 beol  범 beom  법 beop
벼 byeo  벽 byeok 변 byeon 별 byeol 병 byeong
보 bo    복 bok   본 bon   봉 bong  부 bu
북 buk   분 bun   불 bul   붕 bung  비 bi
빈 bin   빌 bil   빔 bim   빙 bing  빠 ppa
빼 ppae  뻐 ppeo  뽀 ppo   뿌 ppu   쁘 ppeu
삐 ppi
ㅅ 사 sa

삭 sak   산 san   살 sal
삼 sam   삽 sap   상 sang  샅 sat   새 sae
색 saek  생 saeng 서 seo   석 seok  선 seon
설 seol  섬 seom  섭 seop  성 seong 세 se
셔 syeo  소 so    속 sok   손 son   솔 sol
솟 sot   송 song  쇄 swae  쇠 soe   수 su
숙 suk   순 sun   술 sul   숨 sum   숭 sung
쉬 swi   스 seu   슬 seul  슴 seum  습 seup
승 seung 시 si    식 sik   신 sin   실 sil
심 sim   십 sip   싱 sing  싸 ssa   쌍 ssang
쌔 ssae  쏘 sso   쑥 ssuk  씨 ssi

ㅇ 아 a

악 ak    안 an    알 al    암 am    압 ap
앙 ang   앞 ap    애 ae    액 aek   앵 aeng
야 ya    약 yak   얀 yan   양 yang  어 eo
억 eok   언 eon   얼 eol   엄 eom   업 eop
에 e 여 yeo   역 yeok  연 yeon  열 yeol
염 yeom  엽 yeop  영 yeong 예 ye    오 o
옥 ok    온 on    올 ol    옴 om    옹 ong
와 wa    완 wan   왈 wal   왕 wang  왜 wae
외 oe    왼 oen   요 yo    욕 yok   용 yong
우 u 욱 uk    운 un    울 ul    움 um
웅 ung   워 wo    원 won   월 wol   위 wi
유 yu    육 yuk   윤 yun   율 yul   융 yung
윷 yut   으 eu    은 eun   을 eul   음 eum
읍 eup   응 eung  의 ui    이 i 익 ik
인 in    일 il    임 im    입 ip    잉 ing
ㅈ 자 ja

작 jak   잔 jan   잠 jam   잡 jap
장 jang  재 jae   쟁 jaeng 저 jeo   적 jeok
전 jeon  절 jeol  점 jeom  접 jeop  정 jeong
제 je    조 jo    족 jok   존 jon   졸 jol
종 jong  좌 jwa   죄 joe   주 ju    죽 juk
준 jun   줄 jul   중 jung  쥐 jwi   즈 jeu
즉 jeuk  즐 jeul  즘 jeum  즙 jeup  증 jeung
지 ji    직 jik   진 jin   질 jil   짐 jim
집 jip   징 jing  짜 jja   째 jjae  쪼 jjo
찌 jji
ㅊ 차 cha

착 chak  찬 chan  찰 chal

참 cham  창 chang 채 chae  책 chaek 처 cheo
척 cheok 천 cheon 철 cheol 첨 cheom 첩 cheop
청 cheong    체 che   초 cho   촉 chok  촌 chon
총 chong 최 choe  추 chu   축 chuk  춘 chun
출 chul  춤 chum  충 chung 측 cheuk 층 cheung
치 chi   칙 chik  친 chin  칠 chil  침 chim
칩 chip  칭 ching
칩 chip  칭 ching
ㅋ 코 ko  쾌 kwae  크 keu   큰 keun  키 ki
ㅌ 타 ta  탁 tak
탄 tan

탈 tal   탐 tam   탑 tap   탕 tang  태 tae
택 taek  탱 taeng 터 teo   테 te    토 to
톤 ton   톨 tol   통 tong  퇴 toe   투 tu
퉁 tung  튀 twi   트 teu   특 teuk  틈 teum
티 ti
ㅍ 파 pa

판 pan   팔 pal   패 pae
팽 paeng 퍼 peo   페 pe    펴 pyeo  편 pyeon
폄 pyeom 평 pyeong    폐 pye   포 po    폭 pok
표 pyo   푸 pu    품 pum   풍 pung  프 peu
피 pi    픽 pik   필 pil   핍 pip

ㅎ 하 ha
학 hak   한 han   할 hal   함 ham   합 hap
항 hang  해 hae   핵 haek  행 haeng 향 hyang
허 heo   헌 heon  험 heom  헤 he    혀 hyeo
혁 hyeok 현 hyeon 혈 hyeol 혐 hyeom 협 hyeop
형 hyeong    혜 hye   호 ho    혹 hok   혼 hon
홀 hol   홉 hop   홍 hong  화 hwa   확 hwak
환 hwan  활 hwal  황 hwang 홰 hwae  횃 hwaet
회 hoe   획 hoek  횡 hoeng 효 hyo   후 hu
훈 hun   훤 hwon  훼 hwe   휘 hwi   휴 hyu
휼 hyul  흉 hyung 흐 heu   흑 heuk  흔 heun
흘 heul  흠 heum  흡 heup  흥 heung 희 hui
흰 huin  히 hi    힘 him
Here is the site and the pronounce graph.

Comment: It would be more convenient for the OP if you could explain how to use this service to find the pronunciation instead. Is this an app?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Google by asking for a translation. In the result there are button to listen to the pronunciation.

On iPhone you can use new Translate app. If you do not have a recent iPhone, you can set in settings : accessibility/spoken content. After this when you select a text , there is an option to speak it.

Answer (score 0):

Google Translapte,
Papago,
Yandex Translate,
Systran Translate

I use them on web browser. Search for them in app stores.